# Excel Pivot table Grand Average instead of Grand Total for sum of head count by month

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot

i'm sure someone figured a workaround for this as there seems to lots of people with the same question...

i need a pivot table that calculated total headcount sum each month, but need to have a column for average headcount between the months selected (on the pivot table)

in other words, i will have a timeline slicer tied to the pivot table and want to have the average for the range of months selected for the pivot.

i found a thread mentioning using power pivot and adding a column of total count, but havent found the solution i'm looking for...

as shown in the snip of pivot table below, i need the "Grand Total" to show average (or a way to have average in the pivot table...

eg count in sept of 56 and count in Oct of  59 should have a Grand Average of 57.5... instead of the total of  115...

[image]

EDIT 1:

i like where this is going but can't seem to get it working. i have the following written and my measure:

MyMeasure :=
VAR T1 =
SUMMARIZE(HC_Data, [data date (Month)], "Total Value", SUM(HC_Data[HC count])
RETURN
IF(
HASONEVALUE(HC_Data [data date (Month)]),
SUM( HC_Data[HC count]),
AVERAGEX( T1, [Total Value] )
)

and get a DAX sintax error

[image]

Comment: so either sum / count or use average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following measure in Power Pivot:

```
MyMeasure :=
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE( Table1, [Date (Month)], "Total Value", SUM( Table1[Value] ) )
RETURN
    IF(
        HASONEVALUE( Table1[Date (Month)] ),
        SUM( Table1[Value] ),
        AVERAGEX( T1, [Total Value] )
    )
```

Comment: i like where this is going but can't seem to get it working. see edit #1, i keep getting a DAX syntax error

Comment: i got it to work!!! thank you so much!

quick question however, is there a way to get the result with decimals? what part of the measure would this need to be in to add 2 decimals after the zero

Comment: You mean you want decimals for the average (Grand Total) but not for the individual months?

Comment: NVM, i completely forgot i can just format it directly in the pivot table... thank you :)

Comment: further to your wonderful fix, i found a caveat i'd like to fix, this solution works perfectly for getting the average of numbers, but it doesn't take into account **0**... so let's say Jan=2, Feb=4, it would return the average as **3**... but if Jan=0, Feb=4, it returns **4**... would there be a fix that would account for **0's**?

```MyMeasure:=VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE(HC_Data,HC_Data[data date (Month)], "Total HC", [Count of NAME])
RETURN
    IF(
        HASONEVALUE(HC_Data[data date (Month)]),
        SUM(HC_Data[HC count]),
        AVERAGEX( T1, [Total HC] )
    )```